# Plotly express: ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I'm having a problem producing a 3d scatter plot with plotly express.

Here is my data frame:

[image: df]

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/alissanicolet./Desktop/QGIS_Thesis/pythongraph.csv')
print(df)

fig = px.scatter_3d(
    data_frame=df,
    x='OSR',
    y='GSI',
    z='FSI',
    color="Samples",
    color_discrete_sequence=['magenta','green','blue'],
    template='ggplot2',
    title='Spacematrix of Sample Areas',
    hover_name='Samples',
    height=700,
    
)

pio.show(fig)
```

Here is my error:

```
ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['Samples;FSI;GSI;OSR'] but received: OSR
```

Is it the semi-colons that are the problem?

Comment: I think you're on the right track? It looks like it's expecting 'Samples;FSI;GSI;OSR' rather than splitting them out into column names.

Comment: Hey! I solved it by doing an excel instead. Now it is properly split into columns :))))

Comment: The heading row has ":" instead of ";". Once file is corrected, read_csv should have `sep=';'`, as default is ','. Post that it will work. Just tried it